# Firebase Configuration Issue : Firebase Analytics is not available

Tags: ios, firebase

As I integrated Firebase push notifications in Xcode swift project.
I am not using pod files for using firebase.
I am getting configuration issue

- [Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available. To add it, include Firebase/Core in the Podfile or add FirebaseAnalytics

[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x46efec

Answer (score 0):

close your xcode project. open your podfile and add - pod 'Firebase/Core' save it.
And from terminal navigate to your projects folder location and type pod install.After it finishes open your projects workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to enable and configure Firebase Analytics in Firebase Console. It provides a simple wizard with realtime initialisation.